# JSTL foreach hidden input submits a null value

Tags: java, forms, servlets, foreach, el

I'm doing a small JEE5 application similar to an online shop and I need to show the shop products, it can be seen more clearly in the code:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productsBean.products}">
  <div class ="product">
   <table>
    <td>
     <c:out value="${product.id}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <c:out value="${product.name}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <c:out value="${product.price}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <c:out value="${product.description}"/> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" action="/servlets-war/AddToCart">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${product.id}"></input>
     <input type="submit" value="add to cart"/>    
    </form>
   </td>
  </table>
 </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that the hidden input value in the form returns null instead of the ${product.id} when the form is submitted.

The associated servlet code is the next:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    ShoppingCart shoppingCart = (ShoppingCart)request.getSession()
            .getAttribute("shoppingCart");

    if(shoppingCart == null){
    shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
    }

    ProductsBean store =(ProductsBean) request
            .getSession().getAttribute("productsBean");

    int id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("id"));

    Product temp = store.getProduct(id);

    shoppingCart.getProducts().add(temp);

    request.getSession().setAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart);

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/shop.jsp")
            .forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: The value is correctly set in the HTML form (check the page source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the `id` as a request attribute.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("id"));
```

Form input is sent to the servlet as a request parameter. Change your code appropriately:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt((String)request.getParameter("id"));
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right, now the application is working correctly.